# Add image to svg circle using D3

Tags: d3.js, svg

I'm trying to add a background image to a svg circle. Below I show both versions but I commented out the part that works. I'm trying to use D3 to create the same elements on the page. When checking the console the circle svg shows up but no image.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
svg {
   stroke: 1; 
}
</style>
<body>
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="d3.min.js"></script>
    <!--
    <svg height="500" width="800">
        <defs>
            <pattern id="apple" height="100%" width="100%" 
            patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
                <image height="1" width="1" preserveAspectRation="none" 
                xlink:href="apple.jpeg"></image>
            </pattern>
        </defs>
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="url(#apple)" />
    </svg>
    -->
    <script>
        // now trying to add same image inside a circle using D3
        var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("height",500)
            .attr("width",800);

        var defs = svg.append("defs")
            .append("pattern")
            .attr("id", "apple")
            .attr("height","100%")
            .attr("width", "100%")
            .attr("patternContenUnits", "objectBoundingBox")
            .append("image")
            .attr("height",1)
            .attr("width",1)
            .attr("preserveAspectRatio","none")
            .attr("xlink:href","apple.jpeg");

        var circle = svg.append("circle")
            .attr("cx",50)
            .attr("cy",50)
            .attr("r",40)
            .attr("fill","url(#apple)");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: patternContenUnits is a typo in your code

Comment: Oh man. Thanks Robert.